# Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need datetimepicker witout time, datepicker. Why it's looking so ugly?

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();//.datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

[image]

But datetimepicker looking good

[image]

Comment: please check if bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css is loading.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because you're trying to use datepicker, but you're including the JS & CSS library for dateTIMEpicker.  They are two separate controls that use two separate libraries.  Just change your script reference to point to bootstrap-datepicker.min.js and bootstrap-datepicker.min.css and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use many `<div>` tags .

Also I think yo need to use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-M-yyyy'
    });
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the visual issues he's seeing.